# How to retrieve a file from bucket that start with a specific string using league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

**Details:**

```
bucket name = eden;
file path = eden/file/eden.jpg;
$string = 'eden';
```

What method i need to use that has parameter to insert my string to retrieve eden.jpg?

**Example:**

```
$s3->retrieveFileStartWith($string);
//this result to eden.jpg || https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/eden/file/eden.jpg
```

**Thanks :D**